# React-native ios App does not show location permission screen on phone, but does show it in simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, permissions, geolocation

I am running react-native CLI.  I am having a problem with the location permissions dialog not showing up on my iPhone, although it does show up in a simulator.  This is an iPhone 11 Pro running iOS 16.3. The code is:

```
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
...
export const requestLocationPermission = async (navigation) => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        const status = await Geolocation.requestAuthorization('whenInUse');

  if (status === 'granted') {
    return true;
  }

  if (status === 'denied') {
    Alert.alert('Location permission denied');
  }
....
```

Again, the location permission popup is not showing on my iPhone, but it is showing running the same code on a simulator.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you previously answered the permission pop up for your app on your phone?  The user is only asked once.

Comment: I deleted the app and built it again.  The popup appeared. Then I ran it again without deleting and the popup did not appear.  So you are correct.  Thank you.